# Count rows between non-empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there i have a similar question to the question posed at

[Move from one cell to another and count the number of rows in between two data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475300/move-from-one-cell-to-another-and-count-the-number-of-rows-in-between-two-data)

In my example i would like count the number of rows between non-empty cells (including the original data line itself) in column A and put the count in Column B

My data starts at A1 and moves down with blanks in cells until the the next data row.

Example:

```
A1 1        B1 3
A2          B2 4
A3          B3 2
A4 2        B4 3
A5  
A6  
A7 
A8 3  
A9  
A10 4
A11 
A12
```

I tried to make mods to the original solution posted but i cant seem to get the count for the last row.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Paul, feel free to mark my answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I quite get what your asking for but try something like this:

```
    Private Sub CountSkips()

    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long
    Dim rData As Range, rNext As Range
    Dim vData As Variant

    Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1" _
                , ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    vData = rData.Resize(rData.Rows.Count + 1).Value2

    Set rNext = rData.Resize(1)
    Do While rNext.Row <> Application.Rows.Count
        lStart = rNext.Row
        Set rNext = rNext.End(xlDown)
        If LenB(vData(lStart + 1, 1)) = 0 Then
            lEnd = rNext.Row
            rNext.Offset(lStart - lEnd, 1) = lEnd - lStart
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Update:

The other way to do it, from your comment it sounded like you want the number by the item after the blank.

```
Private Sub CountSkips()

    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long, lVeryLastRow As Long
    Dim rData As Range, rNext As Range
    Dim vData As Variant

    lVeryLastRow = Application.Rows.Count
    Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1" _
                , ActiveSheet.Cells(lVeryLastRow, 1).End(xlUp))
    vData = rData.Resize(rData.Rows.Count + 1).Value2

    Set rNext = rData.Resize(1)
    Do While rNext.Row <> Application.Rows.Count
        lStart = rNext.Row
        Set rNext = rNext.End(xlDown)
        If LenB(vData(lStart + 1, 1)) = 0 And rNext.Row <> lVeryLastRow Then
            lEnd = rNext.Row
            rNext.Offset(, 1) = lEnd - lStart
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jon49 it works perfect until the lastreal row that contains data. eg Row A297 46, Row A298 Blank or Empty but its the real last row - so column B should show B297 2 not 65239

Comment: I put some slightly changed code on their for you, should do what you want.

Comment: Hi Jon49 Omg your a legend the code works a real treat. Thanks very much for your help. This is the first question i have asked not sure on the protocol yet but i want to ask a followup question on this macro.

Comment: Hi Jon49 - I have a sheet with navigation buttons that navigates records with arrow keys. Each record has variable rows. I need another macro that navigates the record sets. eg Recordset 1 has 3 rows and is the first record when you press the arrow down then the next Recordset to display is Recordset2 which has 4 rows. If you can provide any advice i would be eternally grateful. I have a form that does this but i changed to using an activesheet then the fun started. Trying to reference sheet 3 with Navigation controls and sheet 1 has all the data. Cheers

Comment: Please mark your questions as solved if you have a suitable answer.  You should start a new thread for your new question.

Comment: Paul, yeah, that's new question material, I'm on vacation right now so can't help out, but, if you would, mark my answer as correct, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jon49, i have marked your answer as correct, thankyou for helping

Answer (score 0):

wsworkcenter--> workbook object name

```
WsWorkCenter.Activate
'counting non empty rows , will store count  in the variable mlProjectCount
Cells(2, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select    
mlProjectCount = ActiveCell.Row
```